# What are some references that describe known filters (or kernels) and how we can create new ones?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, reference-request, image-processing, image-segmentation, filters

I'm pursuing a master's degree in Artificial Intelligence. My final work is about Convolutional Neural Networks.

I was looking for information about filters (or kernels) of the convolutional layers. I have found this article: [Lode's Computer Graphics Tutorial - Image Filtering](https://lodev.org/cgtutor/filtering.html), but I need more.

Do you know more resources about more filters (that it is known that they work) and how to create new ones?

In other words, I want to know how they work and how can I create new ones.

I've thought to create a C++ program, or with Octave, to test the new kernels.

By the way, my research will be focused on image segmentation to process MRIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you better understand edge detectors such as Robert or Sobel operators first to understand better how convolution operation on images extract features by constant value kernels.

Would personally recommend [Gonzales and Woods](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Gonzalez-Digital-Image-Processing-4th-Edition/PGM241219.html) for this,  as it gives a pure mathematical explanation to how and why these features are extracted.

Essentially the convolution kernels used in CNN's are ones with a learned set of values for the kernel.

For a better understanding of learned convolution kernels and, quite frankly, any idea under deep learning would easily recommend [Deep Learning by Goodfellow et al](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/)